# Having one query for cucumber bdd selenium automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, bdd

I have 2 scenarios to be executed.
1st scenario returns me one variable as Card I'd.

This card I'd iwant to consume in 2nd scenario

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't preserve things between scenarios and connect scenarios together. Each scenario is a separate test and everything is reset between scenarios. This is by design.

You need to change your approach to writing your second scenario, so it has a Given which sets up your card.